# High concurrent request server in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a simple server that will grab an mp3 file from rackspace cloudfiles, and stream it to a client over HTTP.

The server must be able to stream to multiple clients simultaneously, however, I'm finding it difficult to come up with a viable solution.

Anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several servers that might fit you.

- http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/

  A server based on EventMachine, hence capable of supporting a large number of concurrent and long-running requests without problems. It's currently one of the most widely used servers, as it's fast and frequently updated.
- http://rainbows.rubyforge.org/

  Rainbows! is an HTTP server for sleepy Rack applications. It is based on Unicorn, but designed to handle applications that expect long request/response times and/or slow clients. For Rack applications not heavily bound by slow external network dependencies, consider Unicorn instead as it simpler and easier to debug.
- http://unicorn.bogomips.org/

  Unicorn is an HTTP server for Rack applications designed to only serve fast clients on low-latency, high-bandwidth connections and take advantage of features in Unix/Unix-like kernels. Slow clients should only be served by placing a reverse proxy capable of fully buffering both the the request and response in between Unicorn and slow clients.

Comment: And I just write up a rack application that services these?

Comment: You can use any Rack-based application (including Rails and Sinatra).

Answer (score 2):

Another in vogue server solution for high concurrency would be node.js:

http://nodejs.org/